# Fazer uma Query n:m usando a Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

O meu problema em fazer uma query "many-to-many". Recebendo um ID da View. Ou seja recebo um id da vigararia seleccionada.
 1 Catequese tem uma lista de paroquias e 1 Paroquia tem uma lista de Catequeses; Uma Lista de paroquias tem "1" vigararia.
Recebo o ID da vigararia para seleccionar todas as paroquias, isto na controlador Catequese.
Espero ser explicito.

Método:

```
 public JsonResult GetParoquiasByVigararias(int id)
        {


            var paroquias = from p in db.Paroquia
                            from c in db.Catequese.Where(?????)
                            select new { p.ParoquiaID, p.Nome };


            return Json(paroquias, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Model Catequese:

```
  public partial class Catequese {

        public Catequese()
        {
            this.Paroquias = new HashSet<Paroquia>();
            this.Pessoas = new HashSet<Pessoa>();
            this.Inscricoes = new HashSet<Inscricao>();
        }

        //chave primária e forasteira
        [Key]
        public int CatequeseID { get; set; }
        public String NomeCatequese { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Paroquia> Paroquias { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Pessoa> Pessoas { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Inscricao> Inscricoes { get; set; }
        //  public virtual ICollection<ParoquiaCatequese> Paroquia { get; set; }
    }
```

Model Paroquia:

```
  public partial class Paroquia {

        public Paroquia()
        {
            this.Catequese = new HashSet<Catequese>();
        }

        //chave primaria
        public int ParoquiaID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Nome da Paróquia")]
        public String Nome { get; set; }

        //define a ligação a tabela vigararia
        [Display(Name = "Vigararia")]
        public int VigarariaID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("VigarariaID")]
        public virtual Vigararia Vigararia { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Catequese> Catequese { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Pode colocar também seus *Models* na pergunta?

Comment: Foi editado com os models

Answer (score 0):

Ok. estava a complicar uma não existia complicação.

```
 public JsonResult GetParoquiasByVigararias(int id)
        {
            var paroquias = db.Paroquia
                .Where(p => p.VigarariaID == id)
                .Select(p => new { p.ParoquiaID, p.Nome })
              .OrderBy(p => p.Nome);  

            return Json(paroquias, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```